# Why are there ESTABLISHED packets without preceding SYN_SENT or SYN_RECV

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I open two side to side bash windows, one with: `netstat -anutpc | grep ESTABLISHED | grep kde` the other with `netstat -anutpc | grep -e SYN_SENT -e SYN_RECV`, then I start `konqueror` and go on youtube.

I got two IP to which my computer sent `SYN_SENT` (no `SYN_RECV`) but I got some IP in the `ESTABLISHED` monitoring window that don't have their counterpart in the other bash.

I'm just trying to understand how this whole thing work, could you explain why there are packets part of an ESTABLISHED connection that were never initiated ? I think closing konqueror for more than 2 minutes should close all the connections associated with the software, so if I reopen it 2 minutes after it should resend all the SYN packets.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the handshake just happens *too fast* for your monitoring to notice. The `-c` option isn't *really* continuous; all it does is repeat the output *every second*, and most TCP handshakes in fact happen much faster than that.

If you really want a *live* feed, use one of the following:

- Linux *conntrack* events – shows new and destroyed connections as the firewall sees them:

  ```
  conntrack -E -p tcp
  ```

  Use `-p tcp` to filter TCP only; otherwise it'll also show UDP. Even though UDP itself is connectionless, the states are kept for firewall or NAT purposes.
- Raw TCP/IP packets – shows TCP packets with SYN, FIN, or RST flags:

  ```
  tcpdump -n -i eth0 "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-fin|tcp-rst) != 0"

  tshark -n -i eth0 "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-fin|tcp-rst) != 0"
  ```

  (You can also filter just `"tcp"` or remove the filter entirely.)

Comment: replacing eth0 by tun0 made it work, however any idea on why conntrack doesn't work even after shuting down openvpn ?

Comment: I just wanted to say the same as `grawity`. To see SYN_SENT states just block SYN,ACK packets from the remote web-sites:
`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport 80,443 --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP` This way you will never get an acknowledgment from any remote host to set TCP-connection up in reply to your initial SYN packet.

Comment: You didn't say _how_ conntrack "doesn't work", but it's possible that it's not loaded into the kernel until something tries to use it. It could be that it works for me because I have `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` as part of my iptables rules.

Comment: To set your iptables firewall back invoke `iptables -D INPUT 1`